# Is 'Yours sincerely,' part of a sentence?

Tags: formal-language, valediction

I came across [this page by the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv153.shtml) on how to write a formal business letter. Here they end the letter by saying:

> Yours sincerely
>
> (space for signature)
>
> James Smellsnice
>
> Sales Manager.

Notice how they end with a full stop. I have also seen a full stop used in a motivation letter for a job application before.

Is this the correct way to end a letter, and if so, does this mean the multi-line blockquote from above is all the same sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a sentence. It has no verb. However, it is contraction of "I am yours sincerely", but nobody really uses that today.

Note that there are differences in letter writing etiquette depending on country. What follows is for the UK specifically.

**Yours sincerely** is often followed by a comma, or you can leave it out, but never a full stop. This is the standard close for a letter when you know the person's name, for example: **Dear Mr Smith**

**Yours faithfully** is used when the name is unknown, such as with **Dear Sir/Madam**

As for ending with a full stop after the name/job title, that's not really necessary.

For personal/informal letters, other ways to close a letter are possible. "Take care", "All the best", "Love and best wishes", etc, etc.